# Managing dependencies between web application

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, deployment, ant

Is there any way to manage dependencies between different JavaEE projects?

But not on the traditional sense of *WAR1* depends of *JAR1* and *JAR2*, and *WAR2* depends of *JAR1*, and so on... if this was the problem I could have used Maven, or ANT/Ivy, or ....

What I need is a way to say that if I need *WAR1*, I also need *WAR2* and *WAR3*. And I also need to specify the version of each of those projects.

I'm currently using ANT + Jenkins on the deploy cycle, but I'm opened to other alternatives if they would make my job easier.

Comment: A declarative way ( in the sense of static and not programmable) would be the use of the maven BOM (Bill of materials) mechanism together with the import statement of maven. A BOM is basically a POM that is a declaration of dependencies belonging together.

Comment: But wouldn't this only "bundle" JAR files?

Comment: I am not totally certain, but i think generally all types of artifacts can be dependencies in a BOM. For normal WAR-Projects you can definitely use WARs as dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a maven module/ant task that creates a zip distribution file combining required war files with specified versions.

Comment: I have decided to go with Maven, but I'm unable to find a working example on how to do what you suggested. My best effort so far was to create a uber-jar, but it placed the classes of my other projects instead of the WAR file. Could you please provide a basic example on how to do that?

Comment: Take a look at maven assembly plugin?

Comment: Ok, gonna take a look into it